# Xamarin Form Android API level support?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2019

I use VS 2019 and Xamarin

I try to run the example (new project), but I need level API 19 (Android 4.4.2)

I was set target, minimun sdk. But get error while build

**"Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       The $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for App4.Android (v4.4) is less than the minimum required $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for Xamarin.Forms (8.1). You need to increase the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for App4.Android. App4.Android"**

I have already tried select different Android version (5,6,7), but apart from 8 only.

I don’t. Search on sites they write, simple changed and use.
But in reality, this is not so. In general, is it really possible to write below Android 8?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to **"compile"** using the latest version to use Forms. You can limit the **runtime** Minimum and Target versions, assuming you are are NOT deploying to the App Store. If you are calling Android level APIs you will need to manually check that you are only using the APIs available for level 19.

Comment: Is it helpful to you ?

Answer (score 3):

you could set your `TargetFram Version` to the `latest version`，then set the `Minimum version` to `19`, `Target Version` to the same as TargetFram Version.

- [Target Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/android-api-levels?tabs=windows#target-framework) – Specifies which framework to use in building your
  application. This API level is used at compile time by
  Xamarin.Android.
- [Minimum Android Version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/android-api-levels?tabs=windows#minimum-android-version) – Specifies the oldest Android version that
  you want your app to support. This API level is used at run time by
  Android.
- [Target Android Version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/android-api-levels?tabs=windows#target-android-version) – Specifies the version of Android that your
  app is intended to run on. This API level is used at run time by
  Android.

In general, the Target Android Version should be bounded by the Minimum Android Version and the Target Framework. That is:

**Minimum Android Version <= Target Android Version <= Target Framework**

Answer (score 2):

As described here [Expanding target API level requirements in 2019](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/02/expanding-target-api-level-requirements.html), In order to provide users with the best Android experience possible, the Google Play Console will continue to require that apps target a recent API level:

- August 2019: New apps are required to target API level 28 (Android 9) or higher.
- November 2019: Updates to existing apps are required to target API level 28 or higher.

and in future as well the target API level requirement will advance annually.

So you need to set target api version as required, however your app will work on all the phones with minimum sdk support. Minimum sdk version you can set based on the features supported by your app.